# Using Interface as parameter of List<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class that may accept a `List<IMyInterface>` as parameter in one constructor

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public MyClass(List<IMyInterface> elements)
    {
    }
}
```

And have an EF entity generated as this

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    . . . 
}
```

And an extension for this class that implements `IMyInterfase` (`Bool MyEntity` and its extension are on the same namespace)

```
public partial class MyEntity : IMyInterfase 
{
    public bool MyInterfaseImplementation {get;set;}
    .  .  .
}
```

And at my view model constructor

```
var x = from a in db.MyEntity
        select a;
```

If I try to use `a.ToList()` as parameter for my class it throw **InValid Arguments** error

I was expecting this:
If `MyEntity` implements `IMyInterfase`, then `MyClass` must accept it as parameter.

Am I wrong with this approach? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you use interfaces, why not use `ICollection<IMyInterface>`? You should always look for the least specified method arguments. `IEnumerable` could also work, but you probably don't want `MyClass` to receive a not-executed query.

Comment: @GertArnold Tks for your help, I nned to build a class that accept ``List<T>`` where T could be any class that implements an specificInterface. Really don't understand your sugestion.

Comment: It's just a general comment, not really working to a solution (for that, see my comment below). I mean that `List` is more specified than `ICollection`. If `ICollection` is good enough, why not use that? It gives callers of the constructor more liberty e.g. to pass `Array<T>` of `HashSet<T>`, etc.

Comment: @GertArnold OK, now understand. Otherwise your comment at **Wiktor Zychla** answer... solve my problem. Could you post the answer to mark it as **THE ANSWER**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're having this problem is that `List<MyEntity>` is not the same thing as `List<IMyInterface>`. The easiest thing to do would be to cast every object in the list to `IIMyInterface`:

```
var x = from a in db.MyEntity
        select a as IMyInterface;
```

This way `x.ToList()` will return `List<IMyInterface>` instead of `List<MyEntity>` and you will be able to pass it to `MyClass`'s constructor.

**EDIT:**

As @Gert mentioned in the comments, you will need to modify your query as follows:

```
var x = (from a in db.MyEntity select a).AsEnumerable()
                                        .Cast<IMyInterface>()
                                        .ToList();
```

Comment: But now It Show some error ``Only Entity Types, or complex types are admited on Linq Queryes``

Comment: This sounds like it has something to do with `MyClass`'s implementation and should probably be asked in a new question.

Comment: Now the problem isn't the constructor, now the problem is at the ``LINQ`` query

Comment: EF can't cast to interfaces directly from `IQueryable`. You can (and should) do `x.AsEnumerable().Cast<IMyInterface>()`.

Comment: @GertArnold You got it. This solve my problem, do you want to post the answer ?

Comment: I'm OK with @AdiLester adapting his answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `IEnumerable<out T>` is *covariant* in `T`, you should be able to just do:

```
(from a in db.MyEntity
    select a).ToList<IMyInterface>()
```

Note that `List<T>` itself is **not** covariant (no "`out`" modifier on `T`).

---

Another solution is to change the parameter in the constructor to something that is covariant, like `IReadOnlyList<out T>`, as in:

```
public MyClass(IReadOnlyList<IMyInterface> elements)
```

You only need *one* of these two solutions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x = (from a in db.MyEntity
    select a).ToList();

 var c = new MyClass( x );
```

If it still doesn't work, try:

```
 var x = (from a in db.MyEntity
    select a).OfType<IMyInterface>().ToList();
```

I am not sure if `List<T>` is covariant.

Comment: It mean if any class implements ``IMyinterface`` must be accepted as parameter of ``MyClass`` constructor ?

Comment: @Wiktor, covariance is only relevant for interfaces, so `List<T>` is definitely not covariant (`IList<T>` isn't either for that matter).

Comment: @AdiLester: covariance is **not** relevant for interfaces. Arrays are not interfaces and they are covariant. Apparently lists aren't, of course.